# Need to convert a CURL command with Data to VB.net

Tags: vb.net, curl

I need to convert a cURL string in VB.net but I'm not able. I suppose I create a wrong data string.

This is the cURL working string:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://app.esendex.it/API/v1.0/REST/sms'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-H 'user_key: MyKey' -H 'Session_key: MySessionKey' 
-d '{"message_type": "N", "message": "Hello!", "recipient": ["1234567890"], "sender": "Bill", "returnCredits": true}'
```

...and this is my code:

```
   Private Sub SendMessage()
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://app.esendex.it/API/v1.0/REST/sms")
    Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest

    Dim myData As String = "{'message_type': 'N', 'message': 'Hello!', 'recipient': '1234567890', 'sender': 'Bill, 'returnCredits': true}"
    Dim web As New Net.WebClient
    web.Headers.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json")
    web.Headers.Add(Net.HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json")
    web.Headers.Add("user_key", Chiavi(0))
    web.Headers.Add("Session_key", Chiavi(1))
    Dim response = web.UploadString("https://app.esendex.it/API/v1.0/REST/sms", "POST", myData)
    Dim jsonResulttodict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(response)

    myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)

End Sub
```

Response give me this error:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: To rule out all other sources of error, try to make your two requests *exactly* the same first. There are a few differences which are immediately obvious: Your VB.NET JSON uses single quotes, the curl one double quotes. Your VB.NET code sends an Accept header, which your curl code doesn't. Your VB.NET code takes user_key and Session_key from variables, your curl code has them hard-coded...

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would be done in C#.

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://app.esendex.it/API/v1.0/REST/sms");

request.Headers.Add("user_key", "MyKey");
request.Headers.Add("Session_key", "MySessionKey");

request.Content = new StringContent("{\"message_type\": \"N\", \"message\": \"Hello!\", \"recipient\": [\"1234567890\"], \"sender\": \"Bill\", \"returnCredits\": true}");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The JSON in your VB.NET code is invalid.** JSON requires double quotes (`"`), but your VB.NET code uses single quotes (`'`).

Double quotes can be escaped in VB.NET string literals by doubling them, e.g.

```
Dim myData As String = "{""message_type"": ""N"", ...
```

(Better yet, use a JSON library to create your JSON.)

Also not that your curl code provides `recipient` as a JSON array (`"recipient": ["1234567890"]`), whereas your VB.NET code provides it as a JSON string (`'recipient': '1234567890'`). These small differences **are** relevant: A human reader can infer your intent from context, a web service can't.

Comment: Thanky you to all. It's works